# How to play raw audio data from socket in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, avfoundation, pcm

I need to play raw audio data coming over socket in small chunks. I have read that I suppose to use circular buffer and found few solutions in Objective C, but couldn't made any of them to work, especially in Swift 3.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you know the format of the incoming audio data?

Comment: @Dave I'm getting just bytes, so format should be PCM

Answer (score 0):

First you implement ring Buffer like so.

```
public struct RingBuffer<T> {
  private var array: [T?]
  private var readIndex = 0
  private var writeIndex = 0

  public init(count: Int) {
    array = [T?](repeating: nil, count: count)
  }

  /* Returns false if out of space. */
  @discardableResult public mutating func write(element: T) -> Bool {
    if !isFull {
      array[writeIndex % array.count] = element
      writeIndex += 1
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  /* Returns nil if the buffer is empty. */
  public mutating func read() -> T? {
    if !isEmpty {
      let element = array[readIndex % array.count]
      readIndex += 1
      return element
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }

  fileprivate var availableSpaceForReading: Int {
    return writeIndex - readIndex
  }

  public var isEmpty: Bool {
    return availableSpaceForReading == 0
  }

  fileprivate var availableSpaceForWriting: Int {
    return array.count - availableSpaceForReading
  }

  public var isFull: Bool {
    return availableSpaceForWriting == 0
  }
}
```

After that, you implement Audio Unit like so. ( modify if necessary)

```
class ToneGenerator {
    fileprivate var toneUnit: AudioUnit? = nil

    init() {
        setupAudioUnit()
    }

    deinit {
        stop()
    }

    func setupAudioUnit() {

        // Configure the description of the output audio component we want to find:
        let componentSubtype: OSType
        #if os(OSX)
            componentSubtype = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput
        #else
            componentSubtype = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO
        #endif
        var defaultOutputDescription = AudioComponentDescription(componentType: kAudioUnitType_Output,
                                                                 componentSubType: componentSubtype,
                                                                 componentManufacturer: kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple,
                                                                 componentFlags: 0,
                                                                 componentFlagsMask: 0)
        let defaultOutput = AudioComponentFindNext(nil, &defaultOutputDescription)

        var err: OSStatus

        // Create a new instance of it in the form of our audio unit:
        err = AudioComponentInstanceNew(defaultOutput!, &toneUnit)
        assert(err == noErr, "AudioComponentInstanceNew failed")

        // Set the render callback as the input for our audio unit:
        var renderCallbackStruct = AURenderCallbackStruct(inputProc: renderCallback as? AURenderCallback,
                                                          inputProcRefCon: nil)
        err = AudioUnitSetProperty(toneUnit!,
                                   kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                                   kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                   0,
                                   &renderCallbackStruct,
                                   UInt32(MemoryLayout<AURenderCallbackStruct>.size))
        assert(err == noErr, "AudioUnitSetProperty SetRenderCallback failed")

        // Set the stream format for the audio unit. That is, the format of the data that our render callback will provide.
        var streamFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription(mSampleRate: Float64(sampleRate),
                                                       mFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
                                                       mFormatFlags: kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked|kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved,
                                                       mBytesPerPacket: 4 /*four bytes per float*/,
            mFramesPerPacket: 1,
            mBytesPerFrame: 4,
            mChannelsPerFrame: 1,
            mBitsPerChannel: 4*8,
            mReserved: 0)
        err = AudioUnitSetProperty(toneUnit!,
                                   kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                   kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                   0,
                                   &streamFormat,
                                   UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioStreamBasicDescription>.size))
        assert(err == noErr, "AudioUnitSetProperty StreamFormat failed")

    }

    func start() {
        var status: OSStatus
        status = AudioUnitInitialize(toneUnit!)
        status = AudioOutputUnitStart(toneUnit!)
        assert(status == noErr)
    }

    func stop() {
        AudioOutputUnitStop(toneUnit!)
        AudioUnitUninitialize(toneUnit!)
    }

}
```

This is Fixed values

```
private let sampleRate = 16000
private let amplitude: Float = 1.0
private let frequency: Float = 440

/// Theta is changed over time as each sample is provided.
private var theta: Float = 0.0


private func renderCallback(_ inRefCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer,
                            ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
                            inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
                            inBusNumber: UInt32,
                            inNumberFrames: UInt32,
                            ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus {
    let abl = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(ioData)
    let buffer = abl[0]
    let pointer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float32> = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(buffer)
    for frame in 0..<inNumberFrames {
        let pointerIndex = pointer.startIndex.advanced(by: Int(frame))
        pointer[pointerIndex] = sin(theta) * amplitude
        theta += 2.0 * Float(M_PI) * frequency / Float(sampleRate)
    }
    return noErr
}
```

You need to put data in a Circular buffer and then play the sound.

Comment: p.s. This is code for raw audio from udp 
PCM 16000
frequency 440

Comment: How do you read buffer here and send that for play?? i am trying to understand your code now

Comment: I have raw data in the ADTS format which is coming from the windows machine as host to Mac as Client. But not able to play audio. I have Used TPCircularBuffer for ring buffer. Any help?